# Expression for product of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I have a larger expression that should simplify to some closed-form solution, but I can't figure out how (and neither does mathematica). A crucial part in that larger expression is the following sum,

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\mathrm{min}(a,b)} \binom{a}{j} \, \binom{a+b-j-1}{a-1} x^j,
$$

where $a \ge 2$, $b \ge 1$ integers and $x$ real. Does anyone know of a different / simpler expression for this? Seems related to generating functions involving binomial coefficients ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_functions)). Any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) (specifically, it is $\binom{a + b - 1}{a - 1} \cdot {_2F_1}(a, b; a + b - 1; x)$) and in general it does not factor as a product nicely (you can probably convince yourself of this by plugging in any particular values).  However, that doesn't mean some larger expression containing it couldn't factor or otherwise be nice.